# Setting up routing for Cakephp application on AWS cloudfront and elastic load balance (using beanstalk)

Tags: cakephp, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

I'd like to ask for your help how to setup routing properly for a **Cakephp** web application on AWS. I got Cakephp running on AWS Elastic Beanstalk, using PHP configuration, and then I set an A record for my domain (e.g. `foo.com`) linking to Cloudfront CDN that was linked to the default ELB of Beanstalk. Everything was working fine, until I found out all redirections handled by Cakephp will redirect to the default public DNS of ELB (`elb-abc123.elb.amazonaws.com/page/`) instead of `foo.com/page/`. I know there's something called CName for elb, but I couldn't get it working (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-domain-names-with-elb.html?). And I'm not sure if this is something with .htaccess.

Here's the route 53 setting of my domain:

```
foo.com. A ALIAS examplecode.cloudfront.net (examplecode...)
www.foo.com. A ALIAS examplecode.cloudfront.net (examplecode...)
```

And CouldFront settings:

```
Alternative Domain Names (CName): foo.com, www.foo.com
```

Okay, and here's an example of what I'm facing: 
Schema: client->cloudfront->elb(beanstalk)->EC2
1. Everything works fine when A client type `foo.com` or `www.foo.com` in his/her browser. 
2. The Cakephp asks for login when client is attempting to request a secure page `foo.com/account/index` (e.g. account page), so the redirection is handled by cakephp controller: `$this->redirect(array('controller' => 'secure', 'action' => 'login'));`. 
3. The expecting landing url should be `foo.com/secure/login/` bur what turns out is `elb-abc123.elb.amazonaws.com/secure/login`.

Can someone help me, thanks.

Comment: A lot of information, but please also always mention your exact CakePHP version!

Comment: Hi, ndm: I'm using Cakephp 2.4.3 (the latest one). And thank you for the solution, it's going to take me 2~3 days to update the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the return value of `env('HTTP_HOST')`, that's what CakePHP uses for the base URL by default. It will probably return `elb-abc123.elb.amazonaws.com`.

If you cannot change that behavior, then, depending on your CakePHP version, use [**`FULL_BASE_URL`**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/global-constants-and-functions.html#FULL_BASE_URL), `App.fullBaseUrl` or [**`Router::fullBaseURL()`**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#Router%3a%3afullBaseUrl) to define the proper base URL on your own.

```
$s = null;
if (env('HTTPS')) {
    $s = 's';
}
$fullBaseUrl = 'http' . $s . '://foo.com';
```

In your `index.php`

```
define('FULL_BASE_URL', $fullBaseUrl);
Configure::write('App.fullBaseUrl', FULL_BASE_URL);
```

Or at anytime (assuming the `Router` class is available):

```
Router::fullBaseUrl($fullBaseUrl);
```

Comment: Hi, ndm: I want to say thanks that this works. But however, I finally get what is a CDN, e.g. cloudfront, for: It's a content delivery service to deliver "static objects" (images.. css files etc) and instead of dynamic contents. So AWS cloudfront can't deliver whole website to end user, but instead deliver partial content to them to speed up page loading. Hence, I had change all my images to https://foo.cloudfront.net/foo/ that linked to a S3 bucket. So there is no need to set the fullBaseUrl to 'http://foo.com', just need a cname in DNS! Thank you!